# jQuery Tooltip UI - trigger tooltip after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tooltip Testings</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <style type="text/css"> 
      body { margin: 60px auto; } p { padding:0; margin: 4px auto; text-align: center; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(document).tooltip({
        items: '.tooltip',
        show: 100,
        hide: 500,
        position: { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top' },
        content: function( callback ) {
          var msgid = this.id.split('_')[1];
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/tooltip.php',
            data:'i='+msgid,
            success: function( data ) { callback( data ); }
          });
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_283" href="articles/programming-in-php.html">PHP Article</a></p>
    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_567" href="articles/programming-in-c.html">C+ Article</a></p>
    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_741" href="articles/programming-in-aspx.html">ASPX Article</a></p>
    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_860" href="articles/programming-in-java.html">Java Article</a></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

The above is working as it's suppose to work, however, I would like to trigger the tooltip only after the mouse hovers the link for an specific amount of time (like 2 seconds, for example).

Also, I would like to cancel it's trigger if the user moves the mouse out of the link before the specified delay time expires.

Can anybody please help me out on this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve what I was looking for.

Here is the final result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tooltip Testings</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <style type="text/css"> 
      body { margin: 60px auto; } p { padding:0; margin: 4px auto; text-align: center; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(document).tooltip({
        items: '.tooltip',
        show: 100,
        hide: 500,
        position: { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top' },
        content: function( callback ) {
          var ARTid = this.id.split('_')[1];
          var TTtmr = setTimeout( function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: '/tooltip.php',
              data: 'i='+ARTid,
              success: function( data ) { callback( data ); }
            }); 
          }, 800 );
          $('.tooltip').mouseleave( function() { clearTimeout( TTtmr ); } );
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_283" href="articles/programming-in-php.html">PHP Article</a></p>
    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_567" href="articles/programming-in-c.html">C+ Article</a></p>
    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_741" href="articles/programming-in-aspx.html">ASPX Article</a></p>
    <p><a class="tooltip" id="i_283" href="articles/programming-in-java.html">Java Article</a></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$(function() {
      $(document).tooltip({
        items: '.tooltip',
        hide: 500,
        position: { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top' },
        content: 'Testing jquery tooltips!',
        show: {
          effect: "slideDown",
          delay: 250
        }
      });
    });
```

the `show` property accepts object parameter with the following properties; 
`effect, delay, duration, and easing`.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does work, at least it does adds a delay, however, it does not control it's trigger, it only delays it's contents display. 
In my situation, this is bad, as the content is returned via AJAX (I already edited my code), and I want to load that process only if the mouse stays for those x seconds hovering the link.