# Carriage Return tooltip text in a title tag using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, title

I have a simple JS function that outputs some results from a DB to a JS String. I then use the results from the function in a title tag, so that when you hover over a link  you'll see a tool tip. And that all works, except I don't know why I'm not getting new line when I use `&#Xa;`?  Am I missing something.  Below is the code I'm using:

```
      //loop through returned DB results and form string.  
      //use &#xA; to break line
     function getResults(id, state, dte){
      :
      :
      $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {  
        output = output + x + ". " + val.abr_month +": "+ val.result +" ("+val.point+")&#xA;";
        x = x + 1;
        //output = + output;
      });//end each
          return output;
          }//end function  

     result = getResults(id, state, dte);
     //return the HTML DOM object
     $('#'+id)[0].title=result;
```

The string I see being returned when I hover over the link is:
 1. Apr: Result(45)&#xA2. May: Result (45)&#xA. 

What I want to see is this:
1. Apr: Result (45)
2. May: Result (45)

if you can help in any way, that would be great
Note: I've removed the semi-colon for the purpose i've displayin the text &#Xa
I'm not using JQuery 1.9 so I can't use tooltip
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers will allow `&#10;`

Others will not let you format the tool tip unless you use  [jQuery UI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) or similar

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DKzTv/)

The demo is using jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery UI v1.11.0pre just to let you see that jQuery and jQuery UI can have different versions

the dynamic part is found here:

[jQuery Tooltip UI - trigger tooltip after x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499249/jquery-tooltip-ui-trigger-tooltip-after-x-seconds)

```
var titles = {
    "aprmay":"1. April: Result (49)<br/>2. May: Result (47)",
    "junjul":"1. June: Result (50)<br/>2. July: Result (42)"
}
$(function() {
    $(".result").each(function() {
        var title = this.title.replace(/; /g,"<br/>"); 
        $(this).tooltip({ "content": title });
    });

    // dynamic generate on hover 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523285/295783 

  $(document).tooltip({
    items: '.dynresult',
    show: 100,
    hide: 500,
    position: { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top' },
    content: function( callback ) {
      var title = titles[this.id];
      callback( title ); 
    }
  });
});

function getTitles(obj) {
    return titles[obj.id];
}
```

using this HTML

```
<h3>Static titles</h3>
<a href="#" class="result" title="1. Apr: Result (45); 2. May: Result (45)">April/May</a>
<a href="#" class="result" title="1. June: Result (50); 2. July: Result (42)">June/July</a>
<hr/>
<h3>Dynamic titles</h3>
<a href="#" class="dynresult" title="" id="aprmay">April/May</a>
<a href="#" class="dynresult" title="" id="junjul">June/July</a>
```

Comment: Weirdly though, if I put the returned string from the function directly into the html title, it will display as expected. But when I use this bit of code $('#'+id)[0].title=result; it doesn't.  I guess this is why I need to use tooltip...

Comment: I'm not using JQuery 1.9 so I can't use tooltip :(

Comment: What does jQuery 1.9 have to do with jQuery UI tooltips? I have not seen any post mentioning tooltips not working with older jQuery. See my update for an example

Comment: That's great.  Thanks for your help.  I can see how this works, except the tooltips are dynamically generated when the user hovers over the link, so using replace won't work because there will be nothing to replace yet.  Sorry, I should have given that info from the start.

Comment: Thanks so much. Looks perfect.  I just can't get tooltip to work - Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip' - this is why I thought I couldn't use it with my version of jQuery.  So, obviously I have another issue.

Comment: The reason for the [object Object] has no method 'tooltip error was due to the fact I was including jquery.ui.widget.js which is pretty much no longer required.